# @RepositoryRestController avoids @JsonView annotation, returns all fields of an entity

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Our application is developed using Spring-boot and Spring-data. Some end-points are exposed using @RestController. We are using @JsonView to filter fields. i.e. details, summary...

Now, for more control over rest we are trying to integrate ***spring-data-rest*** with application. Replaced @RestController with @RepositoryRestController.

> Everything worked fine, but api output returned all fields of entity.
>   i.e. it avoided @JsonView annotation, which was working fine with 
>   @RestController.

Any way to fix this?

Comment: was you able to fix it ?

Comment: @Shahbour: still no success..

Comment: maybe the key would be to override repository interface autogenerated methods using this annotation